# Mismatch between computational complexity of Additive attention and RNN cell

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model

> According to `Attention is all you need` paper: Additive attention (The classic attention use in RNN by Bahdanau) computes the compatibility function using a feed-forward network with a single hidden layer. **While the two are similar in theoretical complexity**, ...

Indeed, we can see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/LanguageTechnology/comments/9gulm9/complexity_of_transformer_attention_network/) that the computational complexity of additive attention and dot-prod (transformer attention) are both `n²*d`.

However, if we look closer at additive attention, it is in fact a RNN cell which have a computational complexity of `n*d²` (according to the same table).

Thus, shouldn't the computational complexity of additive attention be `n*d²` instead of `n²*d` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim that additive attention is in fact a RNN cell is what is leading you astray. Additive attention is implemented using a fully-connected shallow (1 hidden layer) feedforward neural network "between" the encoder and decoder RNNs as shown below and described in the original paper by Bahdanau et al. (pg. 3) [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473v7.pdf):

> ... an *alignment model* which scores how well the inputs around position `j` and the output at position `i` match. The score is based on the RNN hidden state `s_i − 1` (just before emitting `y_i`, Eq. (4)) and the `j`-th annotation `h_j` of the input sentence.
>
> We parametrize the alignment model `a` as a feedforward neural network which is jointly trained with all the other components of the proposed system...

[image: Attention mechanism diagram credit to Nir Arbel]

Figure 1: Attention mechanism diagram from [[2]](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/attention-in-rnns-321fbcd64f05).

Thus, the alignment scores are calculated by *adding* the outputs of the decoder hidden state to the encoder outputs. So the additive attention is not a RNN cell.

### References

[[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473v7.pdf) Bahdanau, D., Cho, K. and Bengio, Y., 2014. Neural machine translation by jointly learning to align and translate. arXiv preprint arXiv:1409.0473.

[[2]](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/attention-in-rnns-321fbcd64f05) Arbel, N., 2019. Attention in RNNs. [Medium blog post](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/attention-in-rnns-321fbcd64f05).